# Why does my bootstrap popover not open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues with a Bootstrap popover that does not open. It is not the only popover in the page and others work fine, so it's no issue with missing libraries.

Using Firefox & IE 11.

**EDIT After Solving:** Solution was as in the answer below, because `data-content` was empty. While the documentation of the current Version (3) does not mention this behaviour in any way, Bootstrap 4 alpha Doc says: **Zero-length `title` and `content` values will never show a popover.** This clearly applies to the current version as well.

Please find below my HTML & Javascript code.
In short what I'm doing: initialize Popover and on open populate popover with content in a div (divid is passed as data attribute).

When debugging through the code I can see the popover gets initialized and everything, but when clicking on the link nothing happens.

Unfortunately there are no errors showing up. could someone please lend me their eyes? I've been too long staring at it and can't see no errors...

HTML:

```
<a data-toggle="popover" data-infotype="scheduledlines" data-divid="${posItemStatus.index}" data-placement="bottom" data-title="" data-trigger="click">
      <span class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Show info</span>
</a>
```

Javascript (initialize):

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){

            var init = function(){
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function(index) {
                    $(this).popover({ 
                        html: true
                    });
                    $(this).on('show.bs.popover', onLoadPopoverFunction);
                    $(this).on('remove', function(){
                        $(this).popover('hide');
                    });
                });
            }

            window.setTimeout(init,100);
        });
```

Javascript - Function that gets called on popover open:

```
 var onLoadPopoverFunction = function(event){
            var element = $(event.target);
            var infoType = $(element).data('infotype');
            [...]
            if(infoType === "scheduledlines"){
                var id = $(element).data('divid');
                $(element).data('bs.popover').options.content = $('#ScheduledLines_'+id).html();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: looks like the problem is with the `data-content` attribute on the anchor. It is missing, and required. Here's a working example with that tweak: https://jsfiddle.net/j87vb46L/3

---

Could `onLoadPopoverFunction` be undefined at the point where you reference it? i.e. try reordering the source and defining that "higher up".

Comment: No that wasn't the problem. but thanks anyway. `onLoadPopoverFunction` gets called when the popover opens, but I don't even get to the point where it opens. Clicking on the link that should open the popover does nothing, and there are no errors shown in the console

Comment: Aha - looks like the `data-content` attribute on the anchor is missing, and required. Here's an example showing it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/j87vb46L/3/

Comment: thank you so much for your effort, it works! if you want to edit your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function () {
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

i had tried this, after some changes use this script
this will activate your popover